# Error while using CURL in java

Tags: curl, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

The CURL that i want to convert is

```
curl –insecure -H "Authorization: Bearer c25laGEyMDE0QHZ5b21sYWJzLmNvbTpwdW5lQDEyM2lSWWx6MFdtbjBxRjExcDVyQTE5eDRNNVk" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @Incident.txt https://na15.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Incident/
```

and the java code I am using is to do this is

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String url = "https://na15.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Incident/";

            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");

            String userpass = "username" + ":" + "password+securitytoken_of_force.com";
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());

            System.out.println(basicAuth);
            conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization : Bearer", basicAuth);

            String data =  "{\"srd1\":\"HardwareIssue\"}";
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            out.write(data);
            out.close();

            new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     } 
 }
```

But while executing the code I am facing the below error

> "Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for
>   URL:https://na15.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Incident/."

I am new in doing this, please suggest.

Comment: How and when did you obtain token that you are passing in header?

Answer (score 0):

Error 401 means that you are not authorized to access the URL/resource. I tried to run your cURL code and it also returned a 401 with this message:

```
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
```

Maybe you're not passing the correct `Authorization` header.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to mix basic auth & oauth tokens, which won't work, the Bearer token passed in the authorization header needs to be obtained via one of the OAuth flows. There's lots of docs & articles on this, start with the [online help](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_authenticate.htm&language=en_US)